# Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathfrak{M}, m)$ be a Lebesgue measurable space, $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $E = \{(x, f(x)): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

How can I calculate the Lebesgue measure of E, $m(E)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: fubini's theorem is a good way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, it follows that $E$ is measurable (actually Borel measurable).

Using Tonelli's Theorem:

$$ m(E) = \int_{\Bbb R^2} \chi_E(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_{\Bbb R} \left (\int_{\Bbb R} \chi_E(x,y) dy \right) dx =  \int_{\Bbb R} 0 \ dx = 0$$

**Remark:** Explaining why $\int_{\Bbb R} \chi_E(x,y) dy=0$.
Note that, for each $x \in \Bbb R$,
$$ \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_E(x,y) dy= \int_{\Bbb R}\chi_{\{f(x)\}} dy =0 $$
since $\chi_{\{f(x)\}}$ is the indicator function of a single-point set $\{f(x)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have one question. Why $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{E}(x, y) d y$ is zero?

Comment: @alryosha , Your are welcome. I have added a remark to the answer explaining why $\int_{\Bbb R} \chi_E(x,y) dy=0$. Please, let me know if you have any further question.